# Conditional Probability for fake reviews

Tags: statistics, probability, bayesian

I am working on a conditional probability question.
[image]

A = probability of being legit review

B = probability of guessing correctly

P(A) = 0.98 → P(A’) = 0.02

P(B|A’) = 0.95

P(B|A) = 0.90

The question should be this: P(A’|B) =?

```
P(A’|B) = P(B|A’).P(A’) / P(B)

P(B) = P(B and A’) + P(B and A)
        = P(B|A’). P(A’) + P(B|A). P(A)
        = 0.901


P(A’|B) = P(B|A’).P(A’) / P(B)
              = 0.95 x 0.02 / 0.901
              = 0.021
```

However, my result is not listed on the choices of questions. Can you please tell me if I am missing anything? Or my logic is incorrect?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Example with numbers

This example with numbers is meant as an intuitive way to understand how Bayes' formula works:

Let's assume we have 10.000 typical reviews. We calculate what we would *expect* to happen with these 10.000 reviews:

- 9.800 are real
- 200 fake

To predict how many review are classified as fake:

- Of the 9800 real ones, 10% are classified as fake → `9800 * 0.10 = 980`
- Of the 200 fake ones, 95% are classified as fake → `200 * 0.95 = 190`
- `980 + 190 = 1.170` are classified a fake.

Now we have all the pieces we need to calculate the probability that a reviews is fake, given that it is classified as such:

- All reviews that are classified as fake → `1.170`
- Of those, are actually fake → `190`
- `190 / 1170 = 0.1623` or 16.23%

---

## Using general Bayes' theorem

Let's set up the events. Note that my version of event `B` is slightly different from yours.

- `P(A)`: Real review
- `P(A')`: Fake review
- `P(B)`: Predicted real
- `P(B')`: Predicted fake
- `P(A'|B')`: Probability that a review is actually fake, when it is predicted to be real

Now that we have our events defined, we can go ahead with Bayes:

```
P(A'|B') = P(A' and B') / P(B')                         # Bayes' formula
         = P(A' and B') / (P(A and B') + P(A' and B'))  # Law of total probability
```

We also know the following, by an adapted version of Bayes' rule:

```
P(A and B') = P(A)  * P(B'|A )
            = 0.98 * 0.10
            = 0.098

P(A' and B') = P(A') * P(B'|A')
             = 0.02  * 0.95
             = 0.019
```

Putting the pieces together yields:

```
P(A'|B') = 0.019 / (0.098 + 0.019) = 0.1623
```